# Unity3d doesn't call start() or awake() when scripts automatically recompiled by external editing

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Unity script function Start() or Awake() is not called when..

1. Play application in Unity3d editor.
2. Edit script with external editor.
3. Return to Unity.
4. Unity recompile scripts automatically, and restart application.
5. But, Start() or Awake() of script is not called.

Why?

Added...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main1 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("Start()");  
    }

    void Awake() {
        Debug.Log ("Awake()");
    }

}
```

Script is attached to Main Camera.

Comment: is the script attached to an object in the editor? Please also share your script.

Comment: when application starts, Start() and Awake() are invoked. Those are not invoked only after recompile.

Comment: yeah i know, but the script needs to be applied to a GameObject. So try to create an empty game object and drop the script onto this one

Comment: Please attach the code you have got, and whether it is attached to a GameObject

Comment: is your debug console even open? Lol. It should work. The only thing that amaze me is how you organize your methods. It should be Awake first before Start. But what ever works for you.

Comment: I could see console messages "Start()", "Awake()" at first run. sure console was opened.
I created new project, created above script, and attached it to main camera. That's all. When I edited and saved message as "Start2()", "Awake2()" during application is running in editor, message was not printed.

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to hot swap code (chaning the code while the app is running in the editor)? In that case I don't believe that `Start` and `Awake` will be called because they already is started and awake. Try doing the same thing but in `Update` and you should see the new message

Comment: Yes, I means hot swap. when recompiled, mono object reconstructed (constructor called) but initialization code is not executed because Start() and Awake() is not called.

Comment: It also happenned with me. I'm using a Singleton (static instance) and when it gets recompiled, this instance is lost and I got some NullReferences.